# TCP/IP conditions to end an etabilished connection

Tags: tcp

What happens if the Client crashes and never closes the connection?
Or the server crashes before being able to send a ACK FIN packet.
Are those cases implemented in software?

Comment: The TCP state machine has timeouts for this very situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are, yes.  If hosts A and B have a connection, and the program on host B crashes, or the host B reboots to the same IP address, or its IP is taken over by a different system, then IP address B will send TCP RST responses upon receiving segments from host A.  This will result in host A's connection failing with error *connection reset by peer*.

If host B goes down and doesn't reboot, and nothing else takes its place on that IP address, the TCP connection on host A will eventually time-out as Ricky mentioned.